# opauth linkedin email

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm working on some code and trying to get the email address from linkedin. I have looked at there docs to confirm that they do support sending the email via api now.

I tried to add 'scope' => r_emailaddress. If I look in the raw section of the response I see email-address but this does not seem to be getting added ['auth']['info'] array as email so I have no standerdized way of always getting an email from all of my various providers.

I have also tried the following with out success.

- $this->mapProfile($profile, 'email', 'info.email-address');
- $this->mapProfile($profile, 'email', 'email-address');

Any thoughts?

http://opauth.org/

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being this.

```
$this->mapProfile($profile, 'email-address', 'info.email');
```

You also need to add this to linkedinstrategy.php $defaults variable

```
'scope' => 'r_emailaddress'
```